# Will OAuth2 automatic token revocation upon password change affect web applications?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-platform

I have a web application that uses "htps://mail.google.com/ email profile" endpoints/scopes for OAuth2 to integrate with Gmail's IMAP. According to the following news:

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ro/2015/12/increased-account-security-via-oauth2.html
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328616

tokens will be revoked for certain applications on password change. The main use-case is to address the problem of lost or stolen mobile/desktop devices. This should not affect web applications otherwise it would ruin a big part of OAuth concept. But it is not clear from the news whether web applications will be affected or not. Could somebody clarify this please: Will OAuth2 automatic token revocation upon password change affect web applications?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you are using OAuth 2.0.

If you have a Refresh Token, I am assuming, Google will no longer accept that token.

You application should detect that the Refresh Token is not valid and perform actions to allow the user to Authorize your application.

This may require you to notify the user out-of-band of OAuth as they may not be online at the time your Refresh Token fails.

Comment: Yes, I have a Refresh Token. The web app works 24/7 on my server processing users' email messages.One of big reasons I started using OAuth was that tokens remained valid on password change.

Comment: ... Otherwise there was a big hassle related to interruption of service for users. Many organization required users to change passwords periodically and this made things even worth.